# Ember production build, could not find module . due to module name contains '\' instead of '/'

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

In production ember build, i got the below error while loading index.html.

Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-data/-private\system\references\record` imported from `ember-data/-private/system/references`

I believe module name forward slash causes this issue.

I don't have any entry in ember-cli-build.js file. While analyzing this error, I **found registry contains the below Modules**,
"ember-data/-private/system/references"
"ember-data/-private/system/references/belongs-to"
"ember-data/-private/system/references/has-many"

but some how it is checking for the below dependencies in registry 
ember-data-private\system\references
ember-data-private\system\references\belongs-to
ember-data-private\system\references\has-many

that causes the below missing module error. Any one help me how to solve this error.

Comment: Can any one help how to include the below fix,  https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/9def562a63aa7336ad5d1380954f570709a7b656

Comment: It is fixed with the latest ember-cli release

Comment: @Lux  I will try and let you know. but in the above URL, stefanpenner committed to master that is not yet included in emberjs/data 2.4.0.

Comment: @Lux it's working after upgrading ember-cli version to 2.4.2 . thank you :)

Comment: Still having this issue using Ember CLI v2.4.2 and Ember Data v2.4.1

Comment: @Voles  For me its working with the below configuration, 
ember version 2.4.2 
ember-data 2.4.0
ember-cli 2.4.2
You please try changing the version of your ember-data to 2.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug has fixed.

As a best practice, actively use `~ (tilde)` or `^ (caret)` on your `package.json`. So you can get the latest release when you run `npm install`.